# My JavaScript file can't find a class from another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, class

I'm still a bit new to JavaScript and my problem is i have a class in file 1 and i want to use it in file 2 but when I try to reference it "let something = new Something();" I get the error Something is not defined. I've referenced both scripts in my HTML file with the script tag. Also i'm using ES6 and p5.js
`

```
"use strict";

class Matrix
{

    // makes and returns an empty matrix
    function constructor(rows, colums)
    {
        if(typeof rows == "number" && typeof colums == "number")
        {
            this.matrix = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < colums; i++)
            {
                this.matrix[i] = new Array(colums);
                for(var j = 0; j < rows; j++)
                {
                    this.matrix[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }

            return this.matrix
        }

        else
        {
            let rowtype = typeof rows;
            let columtype = typeof colums;
            console.log('ERROR 1: Matrix was expecting numbers as arguments not ' + rowtype + ' and ' + columtype);
        }
    }

    // adds random ints to the matrix
    function Randomize()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.matrix.length; i++)
        {
            for(var j = 0; j < this.matrix[i].length; j++)
            {
                this.matrix[i][j] = random();
            }
        }
    }

    // adds 2 arrays together or adds rows together
    function MatrixAdd(single, matrix)
    {
       if(typeof single == 'boolean')
       {
            if(single == true)
            {
                for(var i = 0; i < this.matrix.length; i++)
                {
                    for(var j = 0; j < this.matrix[i].length - 1; j++)
                    {
                        this.matrix[i][0] = this.matrix[i][0] + this.matrix[i][j + 1];
                    }
                    this.matrix[i] = this.matrix[i][0];
                }
            }

            else if(single == false)
            {
               console.log('I am currently working on this, please wait');
            }
        }

        else
        {
            let singletype = typeof single;
            console.log('ERROR 2: MatrixAdd was expecting a boolean as first argument not ' + singletype);
        }
    }
}
```

`

that's file 1 with the class i want to use
and this is file 2

```
"use strict";
 let matrix;
 function setup()
 {
    let matrix = new Matrix(4, 5);
    matrix.Randomize();
    matrix.MatrixAdd(true);
    console.log(matrix);
 }
```

and here is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js"></script>
      <script src="matrixFunctions.js"></script>
      <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML.

Comment: @SLaks <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script SRC="script1.js"></script><script SRC="script2.js"></script></head></html>

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. Look in the dev tools console for syntax errors.

Comment: @SLaks in the console it doesn't show any errors with the html only with the JavaScript also if you can see where I've written invalid syntax then can you please tell me so I can correct it

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do it that way you need to make sure `Something` is globally exposed. Either by not wrapping it in a function, or by setting it on the `window` object from inside of a function. Or your second file isn't loaded for some reason (wrong path or something)

Otherwise sharing the contents of your JS files and HTML would be more advantageous to be able to solve the problem.

Your `Matrix` class has syntax errors.

You don't add the `function` keyword before a class method.

```
class Matrix {

    // makes and returns an empty matrix
    constructor (rows, colums) {
        if (typeof rows == "number" && typeof colums == "number") {
            this.matrix = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < colums; i++) {
                this.matrix[i] = new Array(colums);
                for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                    this.matrix[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }

            return this.matrix
        }

        else {
            let rowtype = typeof rows;
            let columtype = typeof colums;
            console.log('ERROR 1: Matrix was expecting numbers as arguments not ' + rowtype + ' and ' + columtype);
        }
    }

    // adds random ints to the matrix
    Randomize () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.matrix.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < this.matrix[i].length; j++) {
                this.matrix[i][j] = random();
            }
        }
    }

    // adds 2 arrays together or adds rows together
    MatrixAdd (single, matrix) {
        if (typeof single == 'boolean') {
            if (single == true) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.matrix.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < this.matrix[i].length - 1; j++) {
                        this.matrix[i][0] = this.matrix[i][0] + this.matrix[i][j + 1];
                    }
                    this.matrix[i] = this.matrix[i][0];
                }
            }

            else if (single == false) {
                console.log('I am currently working on this, please wait');
            }
        }

        else {
            let singletype = typeof single;
            console.log('ERROR 2: MatrixAdd was expecting a boolean as first argument not ' + singletype);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my post to address syntax errors you have. You're likely getting an undefined error because when JavaScript encounters a syntax error it stops processing the rest of the script. Which means your class wasn't being created.

Answer (score 1):

Try and switch around the order which you declare these two script tags in your HTML file.

The order of which you declare them matters because if file 2 depends on a class in file 1, then file 1 must be declared first.

Comment: Ye I tried that and nothing changes so I think maybe it's that my class isn't loding in time

Answer (score 0):

how about using doxument ready. just call function in file2 inside

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ // Handler when the DOM is fully loaded });
```

to note that. since im using mobile i do not have test the code yet.

but i think you can just try it

Comment: I tried it but I'm still getting the same error Matrix is not defined